# TypeError: string indices must be integers in complex json array

Tags: python, json, type-conversion, typeerror

I'm getting an TypeError when converting an json array to an object list.
I have tried to find the solution usong google but haven't had any luck so far.
Can someone help me out please?
The error I'm getting is: TypeError: string indices must be integers

This is the code I got so far:

```
import json
import urllib.request

with urllib.request.urlopen("https://storage.googleapis.com/osb-exchange/summary.json") as url:
    response = url.read()
data = json.loads(response)
item_list = []

for item in data:
    item_details = {'id': None, 'name': None, 'store_price': None, 'buy_average': None, 'sell_average': None,
                    'buy_quantity': None,'sell_quantity': None, 'overall_average': None, 'overall_quantity': None}
    print(item)
    item_details['id'] = item['id']
    item_details['name'] = item['name']
    item_details['store_price'] = item['store_price']
    item_details['buy_average'] = item['buy_average']
    item_details['sell_average'] = item['sell_average']
    item_details['buy_quantity'] = item['buy_quantity']
    item_details['sell_quantity'] = item['sell_quantity']
    item_details['overall_average'] = item['overall_average']
    item_details['overall_quantity'] = item['overall_quantity']
    item_list.append(item_details)
print(item_list)
```

Comment: @khelwood my bad had, it should be fine now

Comment: @Barmar <class 'str'> so it is indeed a string, how do I properly use it?

Comment: Why do you need that loop? You're just copying the list of dictionaries into an identical dictionary list. Why not just `item_list = json.loads(response)`?

Comment: There's also no `store_price` element in the JSON.

Comment: Other than that, you're just copying everything except `members`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is a dictionary. When you iterate over a dictionary with `for item in data:`, it iterates over the dictionary keys, not the values. Use

```
for item in data.values():
```